# How to popup a jquery window to play youtube video?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html, youtube

I need this video to play automatically.  It would be nice, this code can play videos from other sources like yahoo etc..  Is it also possible to use HTML5, instead of jquery?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The function or plugin you use to display the popup window will probably be different from what you are using to display the video. In this example I used the [Overlay Plugin from jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html) to display the modal then used [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to display the YouTube Flash Player. Alternatively, you could use an [HTML5 video player with Flash fallback](http://henriksjokvist.net/archive/2009/2/using-the-html5-video-tag-with-a-flash-fallback) to display the video, but you would still need it to popup your modal first.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/2cxqZiWyW3g&hl=en_US&fs=1&autoplay=1"
    class="video-link">Video 1</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/607RMNoJfl4&hl=en_US&fs=1&autoplay=1"
    class="video-link">Video 2</a>

<div class="modal" id="video-modal">
    <div id="video-container" style="width: 425px; height: 344px;"></div>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        var videoModal = $('#video-modal').overlay({
            expose: {
                color: 'black',
                loadSpeed: 200,
                opacity: 0.85
            },
            closeOnClick: true,
            api: true
        });

        $('.video-link').click(function() {
            videoModal.load();

            var videoUrl = $(this).attr('href');
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {
                allowFullScreen: "true",
                allowscriptaccess: "always"
            };
            var attributes = {};

            swfobject.embedSWF(videoUrl, 'video-container', '425', '344', '9.0.0', '', flashvars, params, attributes);

            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, DavGarcia!  Do you know how to play the video automatically?  This code only pop up the youtube video, but user has to click it to play.

Comment: This example has &autoplay=1 at the end of the YouTube URLs, which should start the video as soon as it is loaded into the player.

Comment: I tried this example, but its not overlaying , nor playing the video. why ?

Answer (score 3):

[SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) is a great jQuery plugin as it offers many different options, one being displaying external content:

```
// Display an external page using an iframe
var src = "http://365.ericmmartin.com/";
$.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
    closeHTML:"",
    containerCss:{
        backgroundColor:"#fff",
        borderColor:"#fff",
        height:450,
        padding:0,
        width:830
    },
    overlayClose:true
});
```

[Bill Beckelman](http://beckelman.net/post/2008/09/11/Modal-Delete-Confirmation-in-an-ASPNET-ListView-Using-SimpleModal-jQuery-Plugin.aspx) has great series of tutorials on integrating SimpleModal with Asp.Net as custom confirmation dialog box.  He demonstrates how to create great client side functionality as well as how to post back to the server.  it really helped get my head wrapped around how to best integrate jQuery with ASP.Net.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the demos for [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) and [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)

Answer (score 0):

[PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) is a pure JavaScript library that displays images and videos in a lightbox.

For your purposes, you need you tag the YouTube link with a special "rel" attribute, the video will then open in a popup lightbox.

Comment: question is tagged with asp.net. So -1

Comment: @piemesons - the author of PrettyPhoto also releases a pure JavaScript library, which can be used with asp.net -- so I still believe it's relevant.