# how to popup jquery window to play vimeo/youtube video?

Tags: jquery, html, youtube, vimeo

I'm building the landing page for an iPhone app, and i would like to add a video modal window to our page.   It would be very similar to: https://path.com/ .

I found this page ["Popup Jquery window to play youtube"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838749/how-to-popup-a-jquery-window-to-play-youtube-video) but i don't know how to decrease the size of the video (I don't want it playing full screen).

Comment: Would you be looking for something like this? http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: You can use colorbox too, http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/, check a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/hSp3m/44/show/

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to use something like [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)
You need to add [JQuery](http://jquery.com) followed by colorbox scripts to your html page,
then

```
<a href="your_youtube_link" class="video_layer">play me</a>
<script>
$('.video_layer').colorbox({iframe:true});
</script>
```

Get the youtube link from the embedding tab below the video on youtube, you can set there the width and height of the frame.