# i want to get preview of my files in popup box

Tags: java, javascript, liferay

I want to display my content (pdf, txt, images, videos) in pop up box.....
as we can see an example in facebook!
How to do that?
For videos we can play our video in pop-up box.
can we achieve this task through **JS** ? Please help if any tag we use in jsp.

Comment: For starters, look at how Facebook does it. There are also plenty of free lightbox javascript libraries out there to choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you

http://letuslearnliferay.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/playing-video-in-popup-using-jquery.html

[how to popup jquery window to play vimeo/youtube video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916063/how-to-popup-jquery-window-to-play-vimeo-youtube-video)